# For each in Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use a for each loop in listing the folders in a ftp location using ftp trigger in logic app. However i am getting unauthorized error for few folders when listing the contents of the folder. At first i thought this was a permission issue, but after couple of runs i noticed that the unauthorized files are varying from run to run. Do we need make any custom setting when using for each in logic apps. Any help will be appreciated.[mylogicapp design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDQN5.png)

Comment: Is it possible the files are 'in use' or some similar condition on the server?  Meaning the server is correctly returning that error because access is actually unauthorized at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not that many settings you can alter on the for-each, however the most important one is the number of parallel executions. How many folders (and files) are you trying to process? Maybe you are running against the FTP limit of max. 900 API calls per connection? It's just an idea though.

What happens if you lower the number of parallel executions of your for-each? Standard is 20.

Comment: I actually tried the sequential execution instead of parallel execution and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Move to the code view and add "operationOptions": "Sequential", as the same level as "type":"Foreach".

"forEach_email": {
        "type": "foreach",
        "foreach": "@body('email_filter')",
        "operationOptions": "Sequential",
        "..."
}

Comment: You no longer need to do this using the code view. The designer now allows you to change these settings on your action.